# APA In text citations, with the same first author and one other author with the same surname

Tags: citations, apa

This seems to be a bit of a corner case. I have two articles, with the same first author, B. G. Cook. The first article has a second author, S. C. Cook. The other article has two other authors (G. J. Smith and M. Tankersley).

What is the correct format? Following the format required for references with two first authors with the same surname (this is what biblatex-apa does):

> B. G. Cook & Cook (2011); B. G. Cook & Cook (2011)
>
> B. G. Cook, Smith & Tankersley (2012); B. G. Cook, et al. (2012)

Alternatively, since there would not be confusion between these two in either the first or later references:

> Cook & Cook (2011); Cook & Cook (2011)
>
> Cook, Smith & Tankersley (2012); Cook et al. (2012)

Or is there some other way?

Comment: Is there some reason that the [normal guidance](https://irsc.libguides.com/apa/in-textexamples) for authors with the same surname doesn't apply here—as combined with the normal guidance for multiple authors?

Comment: @Jason That page doesn't address the situation of one work having two authors with the same surname (as far as I can see). [This answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/44971/41983) seems to suggest the first option is correct, however, my reading of the quote from the APA guidelines does not convince me that the answer is correct, as there are three different authors with the same surname, instead of only two.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many authors there are with the same surname. Give the initial, initials, or full name (whatever is needed to provide unique names, at least on the first reference).